# SQL - need to enter 15 rows per customer into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I need to enter multiple rows into a table (one row per each item bought). The customerID is being pulled from another table (I am not manually typing in)... I have searched and search for an SQL that will help me to no avail :(

example that doesn't work:

```
insert into table (district, customerID, shipper, item)
select 'midwest', r.customerID, 'usps', 'tablesaw'
union all
select 'midwest, r.customerID, 'usps', 'bansaw'
union all
select 'midwest', r.customerID, 'usps', 'drill'

from reg r
```

data in table should look like:

```
midwest, a2234, USPS, tablesaw
midwest, a2234, USPS, bansaw
midwest, a2234, USPS, drill
```

Comment: Your edit clarified my question, while I was formatting it.

Comment: add from reg r to every select statement. and probably where customerid = 'a2234'

Comment: Also, look into creating a trigger or something if this is on going inserts for other customerIDs

Comment: the data in the table will have X number of rows for the same customer...only the item is different, all of the other fields are repeated.  I cannot figure out how to insert multiple rows - all of the customers rows in one SQL versus running a query for each item.

Comment: if I add r.customer to every row, i get error: - multiplart identifier 'r.customer' could not be bound

Comment: Forget the insert part for the moment, you need to figure out how to select the data you want inserted. Then you can change the select to an insert. We can't really help much here because at the moment you haven't given us much information to work with. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Stating you get an error is not helpful. Telling us the error message provides some information.

Comment: error: multipart identifier 'r.customer' could not be bound

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CROSS JOIN` to read the `reg` table only *once*:

```
insert into table (district, customerID, shipper, item)
select 'midwest', r.customerID, 'usps', t.val
from reg r 
cross join (
    select 'tablesaw' val union all
    select 'bansaw' val union all
    select 'drill' val
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `UNION` works, you should repeat the from reg r part for each `SELECT` in the `UNION`

Comment: ok... YES... this fixes it... while the code is not neat, it works and that it what matters at this moment.

Comment: I had to repeat the FROM and all of the WHERE to get it to work

Comment: Yes, that's both the strong point and, in this use case, weak point, of UNION

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table (district, customerID, shipper, item)
select 'midwest', r.customerID, 'usps', 'tables' from reg r
union all
select 'midwest', r.customerID, 'usps', 'bansaw' from reg r
union all
select 'midwest', r.customerID, 'usps', 'drill' from reg r
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next code:

```
insert into table (district, customerID, shipper, item)
select 'midwest', customerID, 'usps', 'tablesaw'
from reg where customerID = 'a2234'
union all
select 'midwest', r.customerID, 'usps', 'bansaw'
from reg where customerID = 'a2234'
union all
select 'midwest', r.customerID, 'usps', 'drill'
from reg where customerID = 'a2234'
```

1) Run Union first without insert for confirming the data that you wanna `insert`.

2) `select 'midwest` has `'` missing in the end. (second `select` in `Union`.)